# How do I expose wp_delete_post()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple, bare-bones PHP script, shown below,  that deletes a WordPress post:

[image]

Line 15 calls the WordPress wp_delete_post() routine to remove the page from WordPress. The code below that removes any images that were uploaded for the page.

The script is called by a $.post call that passes the page id to delete.

The problem I'm having is that PHP complains that `wp_delete_post()` is undefined. What do  I need to declare at the top of my PHP script to expose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to  `require_once('wp-load.php');` which looks like it pulls in all of the core files.

Comment: That still gives me: Warning: require_once(wp-load.php): failed to open stream:

Comment: Then set the appropriate path to that file location (hint: wordpress root).

Comment: I tried require_once('/wp-load.php') but that also generates "failed to open stream."

Comment: Where is your script in relation to the root of wordpress?

Comment: I sorted this out.  The proper file to include, according to several sources, is wp-blog-header.php, which is in the wordpress root.  The wordpress root is in DOCUMENT_ROOT of phpinfo(). Armed with the root I just put require_once( /nas/content/staging/my_install_name/wp-blog-header.php); at the header and everything worked.